Many to many post request DRF
Currently I am trying to figure how the post request needs to be structured to create an object in watchlist.
My models.py contains two models that are linked together via stock.
class Stock(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default="")
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    msrp = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)

This created two tables in my database one called watchlist and another called watchlist_stock. The former contains an id and a user id. The later contains id, watchlist_id, and stock_id.
Here is my serializer for the relevant view
class WatchlistAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Watchlist
        fields = ['stock']

And here is the relevant view for the post method.
@api_view(['POST'])
def watchlist_create(request):
    serializer = WatchlistAddSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

I am using axios to post on the react frontend but I am currently at a loss for how the data needs to be structured to post.
react
api.post(`/api/watchlist-create/`, {
    // Some data goes here
})


I ended up figuring it out after awhile of searching for similar problems.
    @api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def watchlist_create(request, stock_id):
        // Get the stock from url
        stock = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=stock_id)
        // Check if user has a watchlist and if not create one
        user_watchlist, created = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        // Add the stock to the users watchlist
        user_watchlist.stock.add(stock)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

const handleAdd = (id) => {
        api.post(`/api/watchlist-create/${id}`)
    }


You can add a PrimaryKeyRelatedField field [drf-doc] to (de)serialize the stock:
class WatchlistAddSerializer(serializers.ModelSrialzer):
    stock = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Stock.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Watchlist
        fields = ['stock']
You then list the ids of the stock as data:
api.post(`/api/watchlist-create/`, {
    stock: [1, 4, 25]  // ids of stock objects
})


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.

